# Proper reading of MP3 file disrupted by ID3 tags

Tags: c++, parsing, ffmpeg, mp3, id3

My semestral project is due this Thursday and I have major problem with reading MP3 file (the project is about sound analysis, don't ask my what exactly is it about and why I'm doing it so late).

First, I read first 10 bytes to check for ID3 tags. If they're present, I'll just skip to the first MP3 header - or at least that's the big idea. Here is how I count ID3 tag size:

```
if (inbuf[0] == 'I' && inbuf[1] == 'D' && inbuf[2] == '3') //inbuf contains first 10 bytes from file
{
    int size = inbuf[3] * 2097152 + inbuf[4] * 16384 + inbuf[5] * 128 + inbuf[6]; //Will change to binary shifts later
    //Do something else with it - skip rest of ID3 tags etc
}
```

It works ok for files without ID3 tags and for some files with them, but for some other files ffmpeg (which I use for decoding) returns "no header" error, which means it didn't catch MP3 header correctly. I know that since if I remove ID3 from that .mp3 file (with Winamp for example), no errors occur. The conclusion is that size count algorithm isn't always valid.

So the question is: how do I get to know how big exactly is entire ID3 part of the .mp3 file (all possible tags, album picture and whatever)? I'm looking for it everywhere but I just keep finding this algorithm I posted above. Sometimes also something about some 10 bytes footer I need to take into account, but it seems it frequently gets more than 10 bytes for it to eventually catch proper MP3 frame.

Comment: When you read size of ID3 it means amount of data **after ID3 header** so to account for the 10 bytes of header we add `+ 10` to size. If the size is not right (checking in a hex editor?) then consider looking into **sync safe integers** and pass your value through such a function to get a correct size returned.

Comment: PS: Copying from hex editor & paste here... Just show the 10 bytes of a problematic ID3 header. What size did you get via code? and (from hex editor) also tell us the shown offset of bytes `FF FB` for first mp3 frame.

Answer (score 2):

The size of an ID3v1 Tag is always fixed 128 Bytes.

I will find the following description

> If you one sum the the size of all these fields we see that 30+30+30+4+30+1 equals 125 bytes and not 128 bytes. The missing three bytes can be found at the very beginning of the tag, before the song title. These three bytes are always "TAG" and is the identification that this is indeed a ID3 tag. The easiest way to find a ID3v1/1.1 tag is to look for the word "TAG" 128 bytes from the end of a file.

Source: http://id3.org/ID3v1

There is another version, called ID3v2:

> One of the design goals were that the ID3v2 should be very flexible and expandable...
>   Since each frame can be 16MB and the entire tag can be 256MB you'll probably never again be in the same situation as when you tried to write a useful comment in the old ID3 being limited to 30 characters.

This ID3v2 always starts at the begin of an audio file, as you can read here: http://id3.org/ID3v2Easy

```
ID3v2/file identifier   "ID3"
ID3v2 version           $03 00
ID3v2 flags             %abc00000
ID3v2 size              4 * %0xxxxxxx
```

The ID3v2 tag size is encoded with four bytes where the most significant bit (bit 7) is set to zero in every byte, making a total of 28 bits. The zeroed bits are ignored, so a 257 bytes long tag is represented as $00 00 02 01.

Comment: I know all of this already. The thing is, even if I implement reading ID3v2 tag size this way and save it to some x variable, after reading these x bytes the decoder hardly ever recognizes what's next in the file as proper MP3 frame. My question isn't about how to count this size, but rather why on earth after calculating it and reading rest of ID3 there still seem to be some of its data left in the file.

Answer (score 2):

```
bool LameDecoder::skipDataIfRequired()
{
    auto data = m_file.read(3);
    Q_ASSERT(data.size() == 3);
    if (data.size() != 3)
        return false;
    if (memcmp(data.constData(), "ID3", 3))
    {
        m_file.seek(0);
        return true;
    }

    // ID3v2 tag is detected; skip it

    m_file.seek(3+2+1);
    data = m_file.read(4);
    if (data.size() != 4)
        return false;

    qint32 size = (data[0] << (7*3)) | (data[1] << (7*2)) |
            (data[2] << 7) | data[3];

    m_file.seek(3+2+1+4+size);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: why use 7 for the bitshift ?

Comment: Draykoon D, The answer is in the answer above. 28 (4*7) bits are used instead of 32.